# C# polygon to mask?

Tags: c#, polygon, mask, roi

I have x, y coordinates of all vertices of a polygon, say (1,1) (20,10) (10,30), how do I generate a mask with all pixels inside the polygon being 1 whereas outside being 0?
I know there is a function `FillPolygon()` in C# that looks pretty much doing the job, but it seems to me that it does not return a mask in any way.

Comment: what is a mask by your standards? what data do you want to get back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(30, 30);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
    g.Clear(Color.Black);
    g.FillPolygon(Brushes.White, new Point[] {
        new Point(5,5),
        new Point(20,20),
        new Point(2,15)});
}

byte[,] mask = new byte[b.Width, b.Height];

for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
{
    mask[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y).R > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This will of course be more performant if you use direct pixel access using `LockBits` instead of `GetPixel`.

Comment: Can I using something else instead of Bitmap and Graphics? Because these requires adding System.Drawing, which conflicts with my Point class that is already in the project.

Comment: @NickTsui If you want to use `FillPolygon`, I don't see any other way. Otherwise you need to roll your own polygon filling function. There are ways getting arround class name conflicts, like aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is rather old question but in case someone comes around and looks for something similar ...*

If you just want to get the mask, there are much better approaches than referencing System.Drawing and actually drawing onto image in memory ...

```
struct Point
{
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

bool PointInPolygon(Point[] polygon, int x, int y)
{
    if(polygon == null || polygon.Length < 3) return false;

    int counter = 0;
    double intersections;
    Point p1 = polygon[0];
    Point p2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= polygon.Length; i++)
    {
        p2 = polygon[i % polygon.Length];
        if ((y > (p1.Y < p2.Y ? p1.Y : p2.Y)) && (y <= (p1.Y > p2.Y ? p1.Y : p2.Y)) && (x <= (p1.X > p2.X ? p1.X : p2.X)) && (p1.Y != p2.Y))
        {
            intersections = (y - p1.Y) * (p2.X - p1.X) / (p2.Y - p1.Y) + p1.X;
            if (p1.X == p2.X || x <= intersections) counter++;
        }
        p1 = p2;
    }

    return counter % 2 != 0;
}

void Main()
{
    Point[] polygon = new Point[] { new Point(1,1), new Point(20,10), new Point(10,30) };
    bool[,] mask = new bool[30,30];

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
        {
            mask[i,j] = PointInPolygon(polygon, i, j);
            Console.Write(mask[i,j]?"*":".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Which will output like this:

```
..............................
..............................
..............................
..***.........................
...*****......................
...********...................
....**********................
....**************............
.....****************.........
.....*******************......
......*********************...
......************************
.......*********************..
.......*******************....
........****************......
........**************........
.........***********..........
.........*********............
..........******..............
..........****................
..........**..................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
```

Answer (score 0):

For playng with masking, you can use a [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx).

Comment: Say I have a 10 by 10 image, with each axis starting from 1 to 10; Then I have a 3 dots (2,2) (8 3) (5 7) defining a triangle, what I want to have is a matrix with all elements inside the triangle being 1 and outside being 0;